# Can I call windows context menu in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, contextmenu

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WQFq.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WQFq.png)
Is it possible in pyqt or in some additional library to call the Windows context menu like in image?

I tried to find something in the documentation, but found nothing

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with PyQt, since it's specifically platform-dependent; you need to find out how to call the Windows shell interface and interact with the handlers it provides. See this possibly [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4506894).

Comment: The [Windows Explorer context menu can be customised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20449316/984421), so it should be possible to read most of its items from the Registry using [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#accessing-the-windows-registry-directly). You could then create a QMenu from those settings for use in your own application. This should be much easier to control than trying to invoke an external menu, and would also allow you to modify it in whatever way you please.